# Multi-thread to run multiple insert sql queries using Python script

Tags: python, postgresql, multithreading, multiprocessing

In my current project, it is taking 20+ hours to run multiple insert records which are processing data of around 2 MB in size. Now my data size has grown to GBs and will be in TB. It is an I/O bound task. The current program is running on single thread. I am looking to to parallel record inserts, which will reduce the time taken in processing the records.

I have looked into ThreadPool, Concurrent.futures.ThreadExecutor, etc. and still looking to make decision as to what should I implement in my current project to solve this problem?

```
def take_data():
  data = get_data('''select query that return 500+ records''')
  for d in data:
    dump_data(d)
    Update_data(‘’’update query’’’)
  print(f'data inserting in db complete')  

def dump_data(data):
  # runs insert query to dump 500+ record
  # multiple insert and select query to get data
  insert_data(data)
```

I am planning to multi-thread either running insert_data() or dump_data(). What should be the right way and where should I implement the ThreadPool? Thank you for your input in advance.

Comment: Before you look at multiprocessing, please look into using psycopg3 copy:  https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html

Comment: @jjanes that’s a typing mistake, I’ll update it in the question. It should be passing ‘d’

Comment: I ended up using multiprocessing library and Pool method, running 5 threads in parallel.

It is implemented in take_data() function where the dump_data() is being called.

Now with parallel processing, dump_data() function is running on 5 different threads and dumping data at much faster rate.